# Incorrect Java authentication code

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a function for authentication but when I entered the correct login and password it always shows that the data is not correct even if it is correct.

The code

```
private String login1;
private String password;
private String Username="";
    private String Password="";
    @Override
    public void authentification() {
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestionticket" ; // a JDBC url
            String user = "root";
            java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,"");
            Statement instruction = (Statement) ((java.sql.Connection) connection).createStatement();

            String sql = "select * from gestionticket.user " ;    
            ResultSet resultat  = (ResultSet) instruction.executeQuery(sql);

            while(resultat.next()){
                Username = resultat.getString("login");
                Password = resultat.getString("password");  

            }
             if (login1.equals(Username) && password1.equals(Password)) {
                    System.out.println("Successful Login!\n----");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect \n----");

                }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hauling the **entire** user table from the DB into Java's memory:

```
String sql = "select * from gestionticket.user " ;    
ResultSet resultat  = (ResultSet) instruction.executeQuery(sql);
```

And then you're looping over *every row* to extract the login and password:

```
while(resultat.next()){
    Username = resultat.getString("login");
    Password = resultat.getString("password");  
}
```

After this line, the `Username` and `Password` variables will hold the values of the **last row**.

You'll now probably understand that the login would only succeed for the last inserted user in the user table because you're comparing the login against the values of the last row.

```
if (login1.equals(Username) && password1.equals(Password)) {
```

---

This whole approach makes no sense. You're not utilizing the powers of SQL. You seem to be unaware of the existence of `WHERE` clause. You should just ask the DB if the user exists or not. It'll then return 1 record matching the login or nothing. Here's a rewrite:

```
PreparedStatement instruction = connection.prepareStatement("select * from gestionticket.user where login = ? and password = ?");
instruction.setString(1, Username);
instruction.setString(2, Password);
ResultSet resultat  = instruction.executeQuery();

if (resultat.next()) {
    System.out.println("Successful Login!\n----");
} else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect \n----");
}
```

Note that your code has much bigger problems than that. You're leaking DB resources. You seem to be saving the password plaintext instead of hashed. All those casts on `java.sql` interfaces are also not making sense. Make sure that you import only `java.sql` classes and not DB vendor specific ones. Capitalized instance/local variable names like `Username` and `Password` will also not give you extra points as to Java code conventions.

Comment: :I want to compare the contents of inputText with my data in the db

Comment: No. You shouldn't. The DB already does that via `WHERE`. Or don't you trust the DB if it returns the right record matching given username/password? Why not?